# Unable to distinguish between intercepted arc and angle of triangle

Tags: geometry, circles

$\triangle{PQR}$ is inscribed in circle C such that the measure of $\angle{PRQ}$'s intercepted arc is $70^o$ and m$\angle{PQR} = 50^o$. Find the measure of $\angle{QPR}$'s intercepted arc.

When I read the problem, the triangle that I constructed was inscribed in C with all of the vertices touched the circle. However, I wasn't sure what the difference between $\angle{PRQ}$ and $\angle{PRQ}$'s intercepted arc. It seems to me that they are the same thing, but apparently not.

Comment: Read the order carefully (and look at the middle vertex point).  angle PRQ has vertex R and is different than angle PQR  which has vertex Q.  The third angle QPR has P as vertex.

Comment: Let PRQS be a cyclic quadrilateral. The $\angle{PRQ}$’s intercepted arc refers to the arc PSQ. That arc is subtended by the angle $\angle{PRQ}$ at circumference. The size of that angle is $70^0$. That means $\angle{PRQ} = 70^0$ also.

Answer (score 1):

An intercepted arc is the central length that subtends the intercepted angle. The relationship between the intercepted arc and intercepted angle is $(intercepted \space arc) = 2 \times (intercepted \space angle)$. The angle $\angle{PRQ}$'s intercepted arc then yields a intercepted angle of $35^o = \angle{PRQ}$. Since $\angle{PRQ}$ and $\angle{PQR}$ are known for the triangle, we can then find the last side, $\angle{QPR} = 95^o$. This intercepted arc for this angle is then $2\times{95} = 190^o$

The solution to this problem confirms my result.
Everyone who responded to give idea, thanks :)